# how to select a suitable blogging solution for beginners?

Tags: blogging

I want to start a blog that will mostly server 'Programming' related video tutorials/series. Out of the various options out there ( both paid/free ) I am not sure which one to pick and the long term perks.

I want to host all my videos no Youtube and link it in my blog posts.

1. If I do not buy a domain in the very beginning. Is there an easy migration path in future to move my blog to a paid domain and still not hurt the blog raking ?
2. If I start with a paid domain name and use one of the free services available. Is it easy to move the blog data to another hosting in future - Do I need to keep any particular providers in mind to keep this option open ?
3. With my limited knowledge I believe with wordpress I would get option to customize my blog to detail extent. Is there a obvious choice for me here between blogspot and wordpress.

Thanks for your inputs in advance!

Comment: One mistake many beginner bloggers / webmasters make is not being aware of the distinction between wordpress.com and wordpress.org -- the first is a blogspot-like blog network, the latter is the fully customizable, flexible, self-owned, self-hosted solution.

Comment: I've expanded my comment and submitted it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1). You might want to ask a profesional SEO here, but the facts are, if you don't buy a domain from the beginning, then the day you decide to migrate you will have a lot of indexed links on Google pointing to the old address. You will have to ensure 301 redirects are taking place in order to mitigate ranking loss, and I'm not sure blogger and wp.com allow setting 301 redirects (maybe when buying a new domain **exclusively to point to the blog hosted on their networks**, they do 301 redirects).

I've seen a case where a moderately well-ranked blog with 4k+ users per day changed the domain name and it took a few months to recover the previous ranking, even with proper 301 redirects.

You also would lose social networking rankings such as stats on how many times a post was tweeted / shared on facebook / etc.

(2). You don't have to worry just about the domain migration, there's the data migration too. You have to export your content in a format the platform you currently use can generate, and the new platform you want to use has to be able to interpret this format. That, or you'll have to manually migrate.

About the domain migration, usually you would expect it to be relatively painless. Apart from taking between 2-3hrs to a couple days to the changes to DNS servers to propagate to all your visitors, so a few visitors might reach the new hosting and others reach the old one, this has to be properly taken into account before "pulling the plug".

Also, there are hosting providers that will do the migration for you either for free when you register with them, or by a moderate price.

And finally, if your domain was bought together with your hosting space, from the same provider, is not impossible (althought not to be expacted, but it is possible) that your hosting provider might not be 100% cooperative on the migration. In a extreme case, you could buy a domain and not be its actual owner, you should avoid this at all costs.

(3). One mistake many beginner bloggers / webmasters make is not being aware of the distinction between wordpress.com and wordpress.org -- the first is a blogspot-like blog network, the latter is the fully customizable, flexible, self-owned, self-hosted solution.

Comment: thanks. sucks my post was marked closed. worpress ,blogspot are all different software products to me as a superuser.

Comment: @dotnetcoder Well, maybe webapps SE would be best suited for your question, possibly. Thanks for accepting my answer anyway.

Comment: @ruda.almeida it's offtopic for [webapps.se].

Comment: @Sathya is it ontopic for any SE website?

Comment: @ruda.almeida perhaps [webmasters.se], but I'm not convinced it fits the constructive bill